# Can I halve the Amish Friendship Bread recipe?

Tags: bread, recipe-scaling, starter

If you're not familiar with Amish Friendship Bread, or if it's been a while: 
Basically you mush the bag of starter every day for ten days. On days 5 and 10 you add one cup of milk, one cup of flour, and one cup of sugar. On day 10 you again add one cup each of milk, flour, and sugar and then divide it into four equal parts.

Theoretically that is enough to make one loaf of Amish Friendship, share a portion of starter with two friends, and still have one portion of starter left over to keep it going. Of course, in the real world you run out of willing friends pretty quickly. Then you start making more than one loaf at a time. Then you get burned out and throw the starter away. Sounds like fun to me!

So I was thinking: Surely we could add less sugar/flour/milk and end up with only two portions of starter at the end. Then you could just make one loaf every cycle. It would be a lot less burdensome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I usually don't answer my own questions but by the time I got done writing up my question the answer came to me:

1. On day 1 take your one portion of starter and divide it in half. The other half can either be shared with a friend or thrown away. (I promise I won't tell!)
2. On day 5, instead of adding 1 cup of milk/flour/sugar just add 1/2 a cup of each.
3. On day 10, instead of adding 1 cup of milk/flour/sugar just add 1/2 a cup of each.
4. Don't forget to mush/mix the bag each day.

Now on day 10 you'll have two regular sized portions of starter. You could use it to make two loaves of bread. Or you could use one portion to make one loaf, take the other portion and start again with step 1 above.

Comment: Note that sourdough starters are not completely divisible, I have seen reports that you can't establish a good starter in home conditions if you are working with less than 50 g starter. But your half cup of each feedings are safely above the limit. Also, yay for self answering.

Comment: You could probably also find a way to retard the starter si that it wouldn't multiply as quickly.